# How do I select some rows and then others in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, union

I have this query, it works but I'm not sure if it's the best approach and I don't get what I want.

I need to select the query contained in the "IN" clause first, then union with others. Entire row returned must be 40.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tbl_x a WHERE id IN(11,20,30) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM tbl_x b WHERE exam_group='jpx' AND subject='chemistry'
) ab 
GROUP BY id LIMIT 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next query should to return same data in simple way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_x 
WHERE 
    id IN (11,20,30)
    OR (exam_group='jpx' AND subject='chemistry')
ORDER BY id IN (11,20,30) DESC, id
LIMIT 40;
```

Comment: It works but still very similar to my own query. If I set LIMIT to 10, then it won't get the queries with ID (11,20,30). I just get sequential ID of 1 - 10.

Comment: I edited my answer by add ORDER BY statement. See simplified example here: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=a971948a0df03e5319b88778928dcb49&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57